# Simple game design: I'm scared of tons of loops

Tags: oop

I started making a simple 2D game than runs on LAN using C++ and SFML library. The game uses a typical update function every frame with its loop to change state of the objects. The game class stores a vector/list of players and monsters and two maps (one for tileset - just graphics, 2nd one holding terrain mechanics - wall, ground etc).

In loop, I call a `Think()` function (which does move/jump/attack, etc) on every monster (different monsters behave differently but all are inherited from abstract class `Monster` with theirs appropriate override).

The problem is:

1. For every monster I need to loop through every other object to check collision
2. For every monster I need to find near objects (by its coords) so the monster can behave according to what it is seeing
3. For every non-living object (like flying fireball, any other projectile) I need to update its coords according to passed time (this is easy) but again check collision
4. For every player I need to loop through all other players/non-lived/monsters to collect information about near objects to send appropriate state of the game to them.

**I'm scared how many loops/nested loops this game would have.**
I've already seen that some games implement small-instance-based maps world so the loops are always going through small amount of data and since every map is separated its easy to find anything/send update to players.

I could apply this approach to every floor with ease but the floor 0 would be still really huge (array around 5000x5000 tiles to walk on).

I'm thinking now of changing world map array to class that stores references to each object by its coordinates. I just came up with an idea that sorting objects by theirs coords would improve performance of loops or even replace them.

**Is this a correct design? Or does exist a better idea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not worry to much about many loops. You can always optimize once you run into problems.

However for the collision you should avoid to check each object against all others, as this will require n^2 checks. Still, this only applies if you really run into performance problems. If this happens, the default approach is to use a grid, which is updated once per frame (or less) to calculate each object's position in the grid. This means each of your cells will know about all objects in it.
Then, if you want to find collisions for a single object, you just check it, with the objects in the same cell and in adjacent cells.

If you have a big amount of objects, you might consider a dynamically adjusting grid, which can be achieved via a quadtree for example. But in most cases a simple statically defined grid should be sufficient.

Comment: well I have a grid contaning collision but its actually constant during game, I will try updating it if I get performance problems

Comment: Don't worry Xeverous I also thought this some years ago, but with the power of computers these days you don't need to worry and what Howlowl is correct, the only thing you should be worried about is doing collision detection. I would just create a big rectangle covering the screen and then only check anything inside of that. I know Howlowl already said this I just wanted to back him up :)